# Remove Error handler code from vb6 codes auto

Tags: vb6

I have used one error handler code in my all vb6 projects,
Now I have to remove that error handler code which is in all sub procedures, functions. 
I have to remove it manually all the time can it be removed automatically

Comment: Yes it can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried search and replace? It has wildcard support.

Answer (score 0):

I approached a task similar to this one time by writing a small program that would

1) read the project's vbp file and retrieve the names of all the files in a project

and

2) would then edit each of these files and make the desired changes.